# Javascript Running 2 script toghether

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to Javascript, I am trying to run these 2 script toghether but one is canceling the other
I have a form and I would like to compute 2 tasks as soon as the user load the picture through the input file.

1. loading the the new picture in the thunbail
2. write the new picture path to the input text

Any tips to solve the issue will be appreciated. thank you

```html
<form action="../handlers/processUpdatedProduct.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <div class="mb-3">
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="id" name="id" value="<?php echo $product->getId() ?>">
  </div>

  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="productname" class="form-label">Product Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="productname" name="productname" value="<?php echo $product->getProductName() ?>">
  </div>

  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="description" class="form-label">Description</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="description" name="description" value="<?php echo $product->getDescription() ?>">
  </div>

  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="listprice" class="form-label">Price</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="listprice" name="listprice" value="<?php echo $product->getListPrice() ?>">
  </div>
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="listprice" class="form-label">Picture path</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="picturename" name="picturepath" value="<?php echo $product->getPhotoPath() ?>">
  </div>

  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="pricelist" class="form-label"> Picture </label><br>
    <input type='file' id='thefile' name='fileToUpload' onchange="loadFile(event)">
    <div id="rolehelp" class="form-text">Max 500 mb - (.jpg .jpeg .gif .png)</div>
  </div>
  <img src="../../product_images/<?php echo $product->getPhotoPath() ?>" class="img-thumbnail" alt="..." style="width:150px" id="output" />

  <script>
    var loadFile = function(event) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function() {
        var output = document.getElementById('output');
        output.src = reader.result;
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
    };

    var filename;
    document.getElementById('thefile').onchange = function() {
      filename = this.value.split(String.fromCharCode(92));
      document.getElementById("picturename").value = filename[filename.length - 1];
    };
  </script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "running 2 script together". Do you want to run two pieces of code sequentially? Or in parallel?

Comment: Sequentially would be good!